# How many 5-digit numbers are there, such that only one number appears more than once?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many 5-digit numbers are there, such that **only** one number appears more than once (numbers starting with $0$ are also eligible, e.g. $05125$)?

The way I tried to solve the problem was to break it into pieces and examine them one by one, so:

- 5 occurences: $10$ possibilities
- 4 occurences: $10 \cdot 9 \cdot \binom{5}{1} = 450$ possibilities
- 3 occurences: $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot \binom{5}{2} = 7200$ possibilities
- 2 occurences: $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot \binom{5}{3} = 50400$ possibilities

And then I added them up, which gave me a total of $58060$ possible numbers which meet the requirement. Could you tell me whether my solution is correct, as I did not have any contact with combinatorics for a few years and I still struggle with these exercises?

Comment: You haven't accounted for numbers starting with $0$.

Comment: Haven't I? When the only digit appears 5 times, we have $00000, 11111, ..., 99999$, so 10 possibilities (as I wrote). When the digit appears 4 times, we can take any number out of 10 possible (which will be repeated 4 times) and then one other digit from 9 left - then we multiply it by $\binom{5}{1}$, as there are that many places where we can fit the number, etc.

Comment: $00000$ starts with $0$...

Comment: Yes, so what is wrong with my solution then?

Comment: Is $5105$ eligible? because it could be written as $05105$ and therefore not be eligible... The fact that you allow numbers starting with $0$ does not simplify things.

Comment: $5105$ is not eligible, as it is not a 5-digit number. All the numbers (or better called digit sequences) we are looking at are in set $\{00000, 00001, ..., 99999 \}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$58060$ is the correct answer. Your calculation is totally correct.
I wrote a pascal program to verify it: https://onlinegdb.com/BJ0eecZiS